# .NET "Timer" would block other method calls?

Tags: .net, asp.net

In ASP.NET 3.5, we suspect a delegate triggering by a "Timer" will block other method calls. From logs, some function calls will wait for the finishing of the delegate and continue to work.

Is it true? If yes, what workaround can I do?

PS: The delegate contains codes to use WCF to retrieve data and the following code

```
    private void Replace<T>(ref IList<T> src, IList<T> des)
    {
        lock(src)
        {
            while (src.Count > 0)
            {
                GC.SuppressFinalize(src.ElementAt(0));
                src.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            GC.SuppressFinalize(src);
            src = des;
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which `Timer` implementation you're using - there are at least three. If you use a `Timer` which just fires on the thread pool with no synchronization object, it shouldn't be an issue.

The fact that you're locking for the duration of the call will block anything else locking on the same object, of course.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with your specific question, but the `GC.SuppressFinalize` calls in your code are a huge red flag to me. Because of its intended purpose its use is usually limited to the implementation of the `IDisposable` interface. They way you are using it here could be causing resource leaks. Read [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx) for more information.